# Prove this is a subspace of V

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T: V $\to$ W be a linear map between vector spaces and let N be a subspace of W.

Define $T(N) := {v∈V : Tv ∈ N}$. Prove that T(N) is a subspace of V.

I know the properties that a subspace must satisfy, but I don't know how to prove them in this case.

Comment: What point precisely are you stuck at?

Comment: I don't know how to determine if u, w ∈ T(N) then u+w ∈ T(N)

Comment: Hint: If $u,w\in T(N)$ then $T(a)=u$ and $T(b)=w$ for some $a,b\in N$. Then $u+w=T(a)+T(b)=?$.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! The community may give you better advices if you tell us what you have already tried. Some people have already given you some tips, so if you sort it out by yourself it's a good idea to post your solution :) I hope you enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You need to prove that if $w_1,w_2 \in N$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in \mathbb{F}$ ($\mathbb{F}$ is a field) then $\alpha_1w_1+\alpha_2w_2 \in N$ too. So, $w_1,w_2 \in N$ implies that there exist $v_1,v_2 \in V$ such that $Tv_1=w_1$ and $Tv_2=w_2$. Let $v=\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2$. What is $Tv$? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

The set you denote with $T(N)$ is usually denoted $T^{-1}(N)$. In order to prove that $x\in T^{-1}(N)$, where $x\in V$, it's sufficient to show that $T(x)\in N$.

So, $0\in T^{-1}(N)$, because $T(0)=0\in N$. Now, let $x,y\in T^{-1}(N)$; what can you say about
$$
T(x+y)
$$
taking into account that $T$ is linear and $N$ is a subspace of $W$?

What about $x\in T^{-1}(N)$ and a scalar $\alpha$? What do you need to prove that $\alpha x\in T^{-1}(N)$?